# Azure AD Service Principal client credentials grant AUTHENTICATE failed accessing outlook.office365.com mailbox via IMAP

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, imap

I have followed these two guides on how to use client credentials grant flow to authenticate IMAP.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#use-client-credentials-grant-flow-to-authenticate-imap-and-pop-connections

https://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-client-credential-flow-office365-exchange-imap-pop3-smtp

The app registration has the following permissions:

[image]

I have successfully given my application's service principal access to the mailbox I wish to read:

[image]

The obtained access token looks good with roles matching what I want to do:

[image]

I have used both `Microsoft.Identity.Client` and `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to get a token successfully and I have used both `MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient` and `Limilabs.Client.IMAP.Imap` to connect with the token but no client has worked. What could the error be?

```
public async Task GetEmailAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var clientId = "";
    var tenantId = "";
    var clientSecret = "";
    var outlookDomain = "outlook.office365.com";
    var email = "";

    var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

    string[] scopes = new string[] {
    "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
};

    var result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
.ExecuteAsync();

    string accessToken = result.AccessToken;

    using (Imap client2 = new Imap())
    {
        client2.ConnectSSL(outlookDomain);
        client2.LoginOAUTH2(email, accessToken);
        client2.SelectInbox();

        client2.Close();
    }

    var adb2cTokenResponse = GetAccessTokenAsync(clientId, clientSecret).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    var oauth2Test = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(email, accessToken);
    var client = new ImapClient();
    await client.ConnectAsync(outlookDomain, 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto, cancellationToken);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2Test);
    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
}

private async Task<Adb2cTokenResponse> GetAccessTokenAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var kvpList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
    kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", clientId));
    kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"));
    kvpList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", clientSecret));

#pragma warning disable SecurityIntelliSenseCS // MS Security rules violation
    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<domain>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token")
    { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(kvpList) };
#pragma warning restore SecurityIntelliSenseCS // MS Security rules violation

    using var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync(req);

    var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var adb2cTokenResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Adb2cTokenResponse>(response);

    return adb2cTokenResponse;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a global rule blocking `IMAP, POP and SMTP protocols`. After excluding the application service principal from this rule in AD it started working like expected.

SMTP with client credentials grant flow did not work though.

> As per the current test with SMTP Oauth 2.0 client credential flow
> with non-interactive sign in is not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#smtp-protocol-exchange

Also verify that you use the correct SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166725/3850405

Comment: Hello Ogglas, I have been dealing with this issue (IMAP AUTH failed) for several weeks now. I would like to know if you can please elaborate on your solution. What is a blocking rule? is it an access policy? How did you find it? How did you exclude the service principal from that rule? please provide the commands and/or screenshot.

Comment: @meda Unfortunately this was for a customer and my account did not have access to Exchange Admin. I only saw a remote desktop that the Exchange Administrator controlled. When looking around we found a Security Group that stated an exclusion from blocking IMAP, POP and SMTP protocols. When our account was added to this security group everything started working. I would recommend looking at allowed protocols, checking conditions and what rules/policies are applied to your mailbox. This is how we got the past the problem.

Comment: Hi @Ogglas accessing mailbox using client credentials flow and IMAP is working in my case but fails for SMTP, hence I could only able to read the mail and not able to send it. I looked at the link you provided in your answer but over there I did not found anything which says "SMTP Oauth 2.0 client credential flow is not supported", so is it still the case that client credentials flow supports only IMAP and POP and not SMTP